# Dynamic Text Control begins on new page when total data for the control exceeds an entire page

Tags: birt, maximo

BIRT 3.71v20110905

One of my data fields is a CLOB with html tags. I'm using the Dynamic Text Control in my report. This specifically happens when:

1. The Dynamic Text Control content type is to HTML or Automatic
   in my case since I have html tags in the data. (Problem does not occur if I set the content type to Plain, but then the HTML tags show up in the report output as text.)

   **and**
2. The total amount of data to be displayed by the control is more than one full page on its own
   (without taking into account spacing used by other controls). If the
   total amount of data to be displayed by the control is less than one
   full page but can't all fit on the current page, it works as expected (meaning it displays what it
   can on the current page and wraps the rest correctly onto the next
   page.)

Is this a bug in the calculation for the DTC pagination?

Additional notes - I encountered this while trying to use a sample report that inserts a page break as needed between groups for duplex printing. It works great under most circumstances, but not when this DTC pagination issue rears up. ( GroupAlwaysStartsOnOddPage.rptdesign )

Comment: +1 for a clear question with good detail from a new user.  I am assuming there is at least one element or table prior to your dynamic text item.  What happens if you set the page break properties of everything in the area to 'Avoid'?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint, but this is a known issue and has not yet been resolved. At least not in the version of BIRT that Maximo is using.

What I tend to do is break the dynamic text where possible, experiment until I get the largest possible part on one page and put the rest into another dynamic text field.

This is obviously only a work around, but as far as I know there is not much else that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem with a dynamic text field containing HTML content coming from IBM Maximo long description fields. The report was designed in BIRT 3.7.1 Designer.

We were able to work around the duplication bug by changing the layout from Fixed to Auto. With Auto layout, it is also not necessary to change the *Display* setting of the field to "inline" (which we previously had to do to allow it to flow between pages without creating an initial page break).

In our case, changing the layout to Auto did not have negative effects on the appearance or geometry of our report.